# Can not login to sharepoint 2013 central administration . TTP Error 503. The service is unavailable

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have downloaded a trail version of SharePoint 2013 , and i configured it and it used to work fine. but after that i was evolved with other projects. and yesterday i tried to access the SharePoint 2013 Central Administration , i go the following error:-

**Service Unavailable
HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.**

and when i tried to login using the SPS_Farm account the password was expired, so i chnaged the windows password for SPS_Farm account , then i tried writing the following using the administration account inside the SP power shell command line

```
stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin MYgroup\SPS_Farm –password $MYPassword....$
```

i got the folloiwng error:-

```
Command line error.


Usage:
           stsadm.exe -o <operation> [<parameters>]
           stsadm.exe -help [<operation>]

Operations:


           activatefeature
           activateformtemplate
           addalternatedomain
           addcontentdb
           adddataconnectionfile
           add-ecsfiletrustedlocation
           add-ecssafedataprovider
           add-ecstrusteddataconnectionlibrary
           add-ecsuserdefinedfunction
           addexemptuseragent
           addpath
           addpermissionpolicy
           addsolution
           addtemplate
           adduser
           addwppack
           addzoneurl
           allowuserformwebserviceproxy
           allowwebserviceproxy
           authentication
           backup
           backuphistory
           binddrservice
           blockedfilelist
           canceldeployment
           changepermissionpolicy
           copyappbincontent
           createadminvs
           creategroup
           createsite
           createsiteinnewdb
           createweb
           databaserepair
           deactivatefeature
           deactivateformtemplate
           deleteadminvs
           deletealternatedomain
           deleteconfigdb
           deletecontentdb
           deletegroup
           deletepath
           deletepermissionpolicy
           deletesite
           deletesolution
           deletetemplate
           deleteuser
           deleteweb
           deletewppack
           deletezoneurl
           deploysolution
           deploywppack
           disablessc
           displaysolution
           editcontentdeploymentpath
           email
           enablessc
           enumallwebs
           enumalternatedomains
           enumcontentdbs
           enumdataconnectionfiledependants
           enumdataconnectionfiles
           enumdeployments
           enumexemptuseragents
           enumformtemplates
           enumgroups
           enumroles
           enumservices
           enumsites
           enumsolutions
           enumsubwebs
           enumtemplates
           enumusers
           enumwppacks
           enumzoneurls
           execadmsvcjobs
           export
           exportipfsadminobjects
           extendvs
           extendvsinwebfarm
           forcedeletelist
           formtemplatequiescestatus
           getadminport
           getdataconnectionfileproperty
           getformsserviceproperty
           getformtemplateproperty
           getproperty
           getsitedirectoryscanschedule
           getsitelock
           getsiteuseraccountdirectorypath
           geturlzone
           import
           installfeature
           listlogginglevels
           listregisteredsecuritytrimmers
           localupgradestatus
           managepermissionpolicylevel
           mergecontentdbs
           mergejsstrings
           migrategroup
           migrateuser
           monitordb
           osearch
           osearchdiacriticsensitive
           patchpostaction
           profilechangelog
           profiledeletehandler
           provisionservice
           quiescefarm
           quiescefarmstatus
           quiesceformtemplate
           reconvertallformtemplates
           refreshdms
           refreshsitedms
           refreshsitemap
           registersecuritytrimmer
           registerwsswriter
           removedataconnectionfile
           removedrservice
           remove-ecsfiletrustedlocation
           remove-ecssafedataprovider
           remove-ecstrusteddataconnectionlibrary
           remove-ecsuserdefinedfunction
           removeexemptuseragent
           removeformtemplate
           removesolutiondeploymentlock
           renameserver
           renamesite
           renameweb
           restore
           retractsolution
           retractwppack
           runcontentdeploymentjob
           scanforfeatures
           setadminport
           setapppassword
           setbulkworkflowtaskprocessingschedule
           setconfigdb
           setcontentdeploymentjobschedule
           setdataconnectionfileproperty
           set-ecsexternaldata
           set-ecsloadbalancing
           set-ecsmemoryutilization
           set-ecssecurity
           set-ecssessionmanagement
           set-ecsworkbookcache
           setformsserviceproperty
           setformtemplateproperty
           setholdschedule
           setlogginglevel
           setpolicyschedule
           setproperty
           setrecordsrepositoryschedule
           setsearchandprocessschedule
           setsitedirectoryscanschedule
           setsitelock
           setsiteuseraccountdirectorypath
           setworkflowconfig
           siteowner
           spsearch
           spsearchdiacriticsensitive
           sync
           syncsolution
           unextendvs
           uninstallfeature
           unquiescefarm
           unquiesceformtemplate
           unregistersecuritytrimmer
           unregisterwsswriter
           updateaccountpassword
           updatealerttemplates
           updatefarmcredentials
           updatesqlpassword
           upgrade
           upgradeformtemplate
           upgradesolution
           upgradetargetwebapplication
           uploadformtemplate
           userrole
           variationsfixuptool
           verifyformtemplate

Examples:
stsadm.exe -o addpath -url http://server/sites -type wildcardinclusion
stsadm.exe -o adduser
           -url http://server/site
           -userlogin DOMAIN\name
           -useremail someone@example.com
           -role reader
           -username "Your Name"
           -siteadmin
stsadm.exe -o backup -url http://server/site -filename backup.dat -overwrite
stsadm.exe -o backup -directory c:\backup -backupmethod full
stsadm.exe -o createsite -url http://server/site
           -ownerlogin DOMAIN\name
           -owneremail someone@example.com
stsadm.exe -o createweb -url http://server/site/web
stsadm.exe -o deletesite -url http://server/site
stsadm.exe -o deleteweb -url http://server/site/web
stsadm.exe -o enumsites -url http://server
stsadm.exe -o enumsubwebs -url http://server/site/web
stsadm.exe -o enumusers -url http://server/site/web
stsadm.exe -o extendvs -url http://server:80
           -ownerlogin DOMAIN\name
           -owneremail someone@example.com
stsadm.exe -o renameweb -url http://server/site/web1 -newname web2
stsadm.exe -o restore -url http://server/site -filename backup.dat
stsadm.exe -o restore -directory c:\backup -restoremethod overwrite
stsadm.exe -o setconfigdb -databaseserver server
stsadm.exe -o unextendvs -url http://server

For information about other operations and parameters,
use "stsadm.exe -help" or "stsadm.exe -help <operation>"
```

So can my problem be related to configuration settings or it is related to the fact that the trial period has expired . and if it related to the expiry of the trial period how i will be able to update my license in this way !?.Baring in mind that i have run the configuration wizard and it have succsfullly re-configured mt SP , but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: refer the link : http://daniecsp.blogspot.com/2012/11/sp2013-service-unavailable-http-error.html

Answer (score 1):

If your password includes `$` then remember to enclose it in `'` when using PowerShell, so if the above is your real choosen password then the command should be:

```
stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin MYgroup\SPS_Farm –password '$MYPassword....$'
```